# asp.net large file download out of memory exception

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, iis-7

I'm trying to download a file with size greater than 50mb in an asp.net page. But it fails on our production server. It works on development and QA servers. I'm using the following code.

```
Response.Clear()
oBinaryReader = New System.IO.BinaryReader(System.IO.File.OpenRead(sDocPath))
lFileSize = Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileLen(sDocPath)
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" & sDownloadFileName)
Response.ContentType = "application/unknown"
Response.BinaryWrite(oBinaryReader.ReadBytes(lFileSize))
Response.Flush()
HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest()
Response.End()
```

The error I'm getting from the server is as below.

Page_Load **System.OutOfMemoryException**: Exception of type '`System.OutOfMemoryException`' was thrown.
at System.IO.BinaryReader.ReadBytes(Int32 count)
at ExportDoc.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\sitename\ExportDoc.aspx.vb:line 87 Server Name

What is wrong with the code?

Comment: You are not handling your [IDiposable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable(v=vs.110).aspx) objects correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried the below code and it resolved my issue, found the code idea from MSDN website.

```
                  Using iStream As System.IO.Stream = New System.IO.FileStream(sDocPath, System.IO.FileMode.Open, IO.FileAccess.Read, IO.FileShare.Read)
                        dataToRead = iStream.Length
                        Response.ContentType = "application/octet-stream"
                        Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" & filename)
                        While dataToRead > 0
                            If Response.IsClientConnected Then
                                length = iStream.Read(buffer, 0, bufferSize)
                                Response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, length)
                                Response.Flush()
                                ReDim buffer(bufferSize)
                                dataToRead = dataToRead - length
                            Else
                                dataToRead = -1
                            End If
                        End While
                        HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest()
                    End Using
```

Answer (score 2):

`OutOfMemoryException` commonly thrown when there is no available memory to perform such operation when handling both managed/unmanaged resources. Therefore, you need to use `Using...End Using` block wrapping around `BinaryReader` to guarantee immediate disposal of unmanaged resources after usage with `IDisposable` interface:

```
Response.Clear()

Using oBinaryReader As BinaryReader = New BinaryReader(File.OpenRead(sDocPath))
   lFileSize = FileLen(sDocPath)

   Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" & sDownloadFileName)
   Response.ContentType = "application/unknown"
   Response.BinaryWrite(oBinaryReader.ReadBytes(lFileSize))
   Response.Flush()
   HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest()
   Response.End()
End Using
```

Another common usage of `BinaryReader` is using `FileStream` and a byte buffer to control file reading mechanism:

```
Using FStream As FileStream = New FileStream(File.OpenRead(sDocPath))
   lFileSize = CType(FStream.Length, Integer)
   Dim Buffer() As Byte

   Using oBinaryReader As BinaryReader = New BinaryReader(FStream)
      Buffer = oBinaryReader.ReadBytes(lFileSize)
   End Using

   Response.Clear()
   Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=" & sDownloadFileName)
   Response.ContentType = "application/unknown"
   Response.BinaryWrite(Buffer)
   Response.Flush()
   HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest()
   Response.End()
End Using
```

References:

[VB.NET Using Statement (MSDN)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/htd05whh.aspx)

[BinaryReader Class (MSDN)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binaryreader(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: It's a good suggestion, but it doesn't resolve my problem. It works on two other servers. There's something wrong on this server. I've verified all configuration settings, those are same across servers.